# conectar SQL server en WordPress

Tags: sql-server

hola que tal alguien me puede dar una mano , quiero conectar SQL en WordPress.
tengo un Código de envió en php que se conecta a la BD de SQL . Como podría implementalo en WordPress.

Comment: Bienvenido ¿Cuál es el código?

Comment: Buenas, nos tienes que dar la mayor cantidad posible información para que lo que creamos lo puedas replicar con mayor posibilidad de que te funcione, por ejemplo no es lo mismo una versión antigua de WordPress que una nueva.

Comment: dentrada puedes checkear este [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/blogs/brian_swan/running-wordpress-on-sql-server)

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que WordPress se conecte a la base de dato de SQL server ? nose si me explico . 
Algún plugin o elementos hay , para poder hacer esa conexión ?